# Terraform - multi-line JSON to single line?

Tags: terraform

I've created a JSON string via template/interpolation.
I need to pass that to local-exec, which in turn uses a Powershell template to make a CLI call.

Originally I tried just referencing the json template in the Powershell command itself

```
--cli-input-json file://lfsetup.tpl
```

.. however, the template does not get interpolated.

Next, I tried setting the json to a local. However, this is multi-line and the CLI does not like that. Maybe if I could convert to single line ?

Any sugestions or guidance welcome !!
Thanks

JSON (.tpl or variable)

```
{
    "CatalogId": "${account_id}",
    "DataLakeSettings": {
        "DataLakeAdmins": [
            {
                "DataLakePrincipalIdentifier": "arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:role/Role1"
            },
            {
                "DataLakePrincipalIdentifier": "arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:role/Role2"
            }
        ],
        "CreateDatabaseDefaultPermissions": [],
        "CreateTableDefaultPermissions": []
    }
}
```

.tf

```
locals {
  assume_role_arn  = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/role_to_assume"
  lf_json_settings = templatefile("${path.module}/lfsetup.tpl", { account_id = local.account_id})
  cli_region = "region"
}

resource "null_resource" "settings" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = templatefile("${path.module}/scripts/settings.ps1", { role_arn = local.assume_role_arn, json_settings = local.lf_json_settings, region = local.cli_region})
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

.ps

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$json = aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${role_arn} --role-session-name sessionname
$accessTokens = ConvertFrom-Json (-join $json)
$env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = $accessTokens.Credentials.AccessKeyId
$env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = $accessTokens.Credentials.SecretAccessKey
$env:AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = $accessTokens.Credentials.SessionToken
aws lakeformation put-data-lake-settings --cli-input-json file://lfsetup.tpl --region ${region}
$env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ""
$env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ""
$env:AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = ""
```

Output:
For these I put the template output into a local and passed the local to powershell. Then did variations with/out jsonencde and trying to replace '\n'. Strange results in some cases:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html)?

Comment: Yes, but still get the multi-line issue . I'll go do that again and post output shorlty.

Answer (score 0):

Use file provisioner to create .json file from rendered .tpl file:

```
locals {
  ...
  settings_json_file = "/tmp/lfsetup.json"
}

resource "null_resource" "settings" {
   provisioner "file" {
     content     = templatefile("${path.module}/lfsetup.tpl", { account_id = local.account_id})
     destination = local.settings_json_file
   }
   provisioner "local-exec" {
     command     = templatefile("${path.module}/scripts/settings.ps1", role_arn = local.assume_role_arn, json_settings = local.settings_json_file, region = local.cli_region})
     interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
   }
}
```

Update your .ps file
replace `file://lfsetup.tpl` by `file://${json_settings}`

```
aws lakeformation put-data-lake-settings --cli-input-json file://${json_settings} --region ${region}
```

Comment: oooh - that looks neat. Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know how I get on !

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsonencode) function